# How do I determine the row in NSTableView that represents a specific object instance?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, core-data, nstableview

I have a NSTableView driven by NSManagedObject/CoreData and a custom graph view on the same form which plots each row on a X/Y grid based on some derived calculations.  Each point on the graph view causes and event to run a (SEL)Selector on my window controller..

And I am stuck !  I want to be able to change the selection in the NSTableView to be the object selected and returned by the graph view.  ie. use the graph to change the selection/row in the NSTableView list.

I have a method as follows:

```
-(void)setSelectedOpportunity:(Opportunity *)opty
{
    _selectedOpportunity = opty;
    [_opportunityTable selectRowIndexes:???? byExtendingSelection:NO]; 
}
```

_opportunityTable is an NSTableView that gets is content from and NSArrayController called _opportunityAC.  This array controller gets its data from a NSManagedObjectContext containing NSManaged objects called Opportunity.

Can anyone tell me how do I determine the row in the table that represents the object opty.

Thanks 
Ian

Comment: Solved ... -(void)setSelectedOpportunity:(Opportunity *)opty
{
    [_opportunityAC setSelectedObjects: @[opty];
}

Comment: You are allowed to answer your own question.